Cuando and Cuándo in the future .Also, with subjunctive or indicative
I listened to two very good episodes of Espanol Automático about ''Cuando'' and ''Cuándo'' in the future tense most specifically.
Here are the links:
https://www.spanish.academy/blog/9-types-of-subordinating-conjunctions-in-spanish-that-will-supercharge-your-fluency/
https://www.espanolautomatico.com/podcasts/espanol-automatico-podcast/episodes/2148521894
Please note a full free transcript of each episode is available under ''ver episodio''.
I believe I understand mostly what the podcaster explained grammatically.My problem is ,like, a lot of grammar  rules ,I would like to practice them with some answers given.
Like a Fill-in-the-blanks questions examples.
Anyway, there don't seem to be any available online like in Kwiziq and I have looked on grammar websites also. My grammar books have also left me down.
Can anyone recommend me something?  If it is free,all the better.
I have tried using AI to give me questions but firstly it takes ages for it to fully understand and its Spanish grammar(a bit like my own)isn't always that reliable.I refer specifically to this type of grammar rule with ''cuando'' and ''cuándo''.
Also, could people here give example sentences simply translated?

The rules governing the use of "cuando" and "cuándo" and the tenses used after them to refer to the future time are as follows:

The conjunction "cuando" (unstressed) is always followed by present subjunctive to refer to the future (notice that present simple is used in English):

Cuando me jubile, viajaré por todo el mundo. (When I retire, I'll travel around the world)

Cuando tenga dinero, me compraré una casa en la playa. (When I have money, I'll buy myself a house by the beach)


This "cuando" can be expanded into "cuando llegue el momento en que" (when the time comes for sb. to...) and introduces the time framework of the main verb (the time of travelling, the time of buying a house).

The interrogative (or exclamatory) adverb "cuándo" (stressed) is followed by future to refer to the future (just as in English):

No sé cuándo me jubilaré para poder viajar por todo el mundo. (I don't know when I'll retire to be able to travel around the world)

Quiero que me digas cuándo tendré dinero para comprarme una casa en la playa. (I want you to tell me when I'll have money to buy myself a house by the beach)


This "cuándo" can be expanded into "en qué momento" and introduces an indirect question, the direct version of which is: When will I retire? When will I have money?

.Great. I understand.What is tricky for Enhlish speakers to get their heads around is the example given in the podcast" cuando cumplas quince años" . I  mean ,let's say your birthday is in 2 days time,it is ALMOST a certainty you will get to celebrate  it. I know,what will happen at it may be open to speculation ,eventualities etc. I guess we have to bear in mind ,like you said the subjuntive is always used for the future with cuando.
